# Flutter : Dynamic Link not launching the app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using firebase dynamic links to open the email verification link in my app, but unfortunetly the link doesn't launch the app when tapped.

**What I've done so far**

When a new user is created, a link is sent by email to be verified :

```dart
if(firebaseUser != null && !firebaseUser.emailVerified){
        await createUserInDatabaseIfNew(firebaseUser);
        var actionCodeSettings = auth.ActionCodeSettings(
          url: 'https://muslimcoloc.page.link/?email=${firebaseUser.email}',
          dynamicLinkDomain: "muslimcoloc.page.link",
          androidInstallApp: true,
          androidMinimumVersion: "12",
          androidPackageName: "com.app.muslim_coloc",
          iOSBundleId: "com.muslim_coloc.ios",
          handleCodeInApp: true,
        );
        await firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification(actionCodeSettings);
      }
```

I got the dynamicLinkDomain in the firebase console :

[image]

Then, I handle the reception of the link in my `main.dart` file, with the [firebase dynamic links package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links) :

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(
    MyApp(),
  );
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 MyApp({Key key, })  :  super(key: key);
 
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return AppView();
 }
}

class AppView extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppView({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppViewState createState() => _AppViewState();
}
class _AppViewState extends State<AppView> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
       this.initDynamicLinks();
    }
  }
 
 void initDynamicLinks() async {
      FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
          final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;
          FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

          //Get actionCode from the dynamicLink
          var actionCode = deepLink.queryParameters['oobCode'];

          try {
            await auth.checkActionCode(actionCode);
            await auth.applyActionCode(actionCode);

            // If successful, reload the user:
            auth.currentUser.reload();
          } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
            if (e.code == 'invalid-action-code') {
              print('The code is invalid.');
            }
          }

          if (deepLink != null) {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, deepLink.path);
          }
        },
        onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
          print('onLinkError');
          print(e.message);
        }
      );
      
      final PendingDynamicLinkData data = 
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
      final Uri deepLink = data?.link;

      if (deepLink != null) {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, deepLink.path);
      }
    }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(...)
}
```

When I tap the link of the email, the app doesn't start nor does the browser. Here's what happens :

[image]

It tries to launch something on the browser, but then comes back to gmail.

However if I click on the link in a desktop browser, it works fine, the email is validated.

I'm having a hard time understanding what it going on. Is there something wrong about how I did things ?

Comment: Are you successfully handling dynamic link in your app besides this email link? Or all dynamic links don't work on phone?

Comment: I don't know, this is the first one I'm trying to implement :/

Comment: What version of dynamic links are you using, in order to help you better?

Comment: You mean the version of the package ? The last one `^0.8.0`

Comment: I posted an answer with working code, kindly check it out and let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: @user54517 has the same issue, can you show me your code on git? Have no idea how to implement(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write a function to handle your dynamic links, as per the documentation, and this is working for me in an app being used currently:

```
void handleDynamicLinks() async {
    ///To bring INTO FOREGROUND FROM DYNAMIC LINK.
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
      onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLinkData) async {
        await _handleDeepLink(dynamicLinkData);
      },
      onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
        print('DynamicLink Failed: ${e.message}');
        return e.message;
      },
    );

    final PendingDynamicLinkData data =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    _handleDeepLink(data);
  }

  // bool _deeplink = true;
  _handleDeepLink(PendingDynamicLinkData data) async {
  
     final Uri? deeplink = data.link;
    if (deeplink != null) {
      print('Handling Deep Link | deepLink: $deeplink');
  }
}
```

and in initState:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    handleDynamicLinks();
    super.initState();
}
```

write this logic in your home page. Not in `void(main..etc)`
But in your first widget after that, and it should work.

Also, be sure to double check your package name, i.e `com.example.yourAwesomeApp123`, it's what lets the whole system know what app is to be opened when the dynamic link is pressed.

Comment: So, compared to what I had, what you did is : 1) getting rid of the `WidgetsBindingObserver`, I used it to run the code when the app was on pause, but ok it's the same. 2) refactoring the content of `onSuccess` in a method rather than putting the code right in it (which technically should be the same, isn't it ?) I tried these modification but unfortunately, the issue is still the same. The app is not launched :/

Comment: How are you generating your dynamic links? Follow the documentation on generating it from your code, not firebase console. This could mean that the link is faulty, we can't rule out without trying to do it programatically.

Comment: Well, I just followed the official doc https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#open-link-in-app

Comment: please post the part where you are generating the link in YOUR code.

Comment: Well I'm not doing anything other than what I posted. I probably don't understand very well how the link is generated, I thought that  `await firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification(actionCodeSettings);` would automatically do that

Comment: So, from what I understand, the dynamic link is automatically generated : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/ActionCodeSettings

Comment: use a print statement after this line `var actionCode = deepLink.queryParameters['oobCode'];`, to see the code if it's being captured or handled correctly. Also the docs you referenced are for native android and not flutter, so beware there might be some diferences.

Comment: The thing is that this part of the code is not even triggered. It is never executed as the app doesn't restart

Comment: that means that your app bundle or package name isn'tb eing added to the dynamic link. That's the only way for the device to know what app to launch.

Comment: After further investigation, it appeared that you were right, the package name was not correct and for some reason I also added that : https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2399#issuecomment-743760234 Could you update your response for the future people that would face that problem ?